# How to Show Financial Months(from april to march) in repeater with textBoxes to fill some numeric value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am creating a page in which on selection of current financial year say 2014-2014
i want to see financial months like april to march and in front of every month i need text boxes to save values. all these i have to do with asp repeater control. please help
i want to show all months by using sql query using repeater databind

already i ahd filled year in dropdown like this

```
    Dim intYear As Integer = DateTime.Now.Year
    Dim i As Integer = 0

    For i = 0 To 1
        cboYear.Items.Add(New ListItem((intYear + i).ToString() + " - " + (intYear + i + 1).ToString(), (intYear + i).ToString()))
    Next
```

Comment: you might want to add the appropriate ASP tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , 4 , 0 ) - 1 ) as mn
union
Select DateName( month , DateAdd( month , 5 , 0 ) - 1 ) as mn
  like this way you can fill all months

at last do 1,2,3